# Is there a way to save the results of a trained FastTree-Algorithm -Model in ML.NET?

Tags: c#, ml.net

I know that I can save models as zip in general, but does FastTree contain some parameters/result like linear regression w+b that I can just store instead of the whole model? If yes, how to do this code-wise?

Comment: You just want to save the model weights instead of everything you get with `Model.Save`?

Comment: Yeah, but it is a FastTree, I am not sure if this model does contain easy parameters